# Mapped Drives pinning - when I pin a second location in the same path/server, the first disappears

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, pinning

When trying to pin multiple mapped drives (whose locations are on the same server) by dragging them from the Explorer window to the taskbar icon, the first drive pins properly.  When I drag the second, it replaces the first drive that I had previously pinned.

Is there any way to keep them both (or multiple drives/locations) pinned?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. #### Create Generic EXE File

   > Open Notepad (note: leave the notepad document blank!)
   >   Click on "File" and "Save as"
   >   Navigate to your desktop.
   >   Under Save as type, change it to "All Files (*.*)"
   >   Type in a name you want for this (e.g., `U Drive.exe`)
   >   with the `.exe` file extension at the end, and click on the Save button
2. #### Pin EXE to Taskbar

   > Minimize to your desktop
   >   Right click on the saved `.exe` file on your desktop (e.g., `U Drive.exe`),
   >   and click on "Pin to Taskbar"
3. #### Modify Target of EXE File

   > Now your icon should be on the taskbar
   >   Right click on the new icon
   >   On the jump-list that appears, right-click again on your exe file (e.g., `U Drive.exe`)
   >   and select "Properties"
   >   Change the "Target" to your mapped drive letter (e.g., `U:\`)
   >   Clear all text from the "Start In" box
   >   Click OK

Source: [How to Pin a Mapped Drive to your Taskbar in Windows 7](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/3470-how-to-pin-a-mapped-drive-to-your-taskbar-in-windows-7).